# differences between groups and post hoc analysis

Tags: r

Hi i'm a new student of statistics and i'm trying to make some exercises with rstudio.

I try to create a question "differences between groups" and i have created this dataset for the incidence of Hepatite B in different age classes.

"Are there significant differences in the incidence of hepatitis B among young people, adults and the elderly with respect to the year of incidence?"

```
Year Youngs   Adults    Olds
1997 0,16     0,79    0,04
1998 0,17     0,78    0,05
1999 0,14     0,82    0,04
2000 0,13     0,81    0,06
2001 0,12     0,82    0,06
2002 0,14     0,82    0,04
2003 0,11     0,84    0,04
...
2022
```

Which kind of test can i make with this dataset to respond at my question? Anova? if yes, which kind of post hoc analysis i have to do? which graphs are useful to implement in the analisys?

Thank you

I am not totally sure about my question (if it's really a differences between groups)
Not sure if my dataset has sense for anova
in which other ways can continue this analysis?

Comment: I formatted your table for you.

Comment: I don't completely understand your question, I think there may be language issues. Do you want to compare the year that the different groups got Hepatitis? Or the total incidence over time? Or the trend over time? Or what?

Comment: How do you calculate the incidence ?